# Port array of strings to array of dictionaries each containing a string

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to port the strings in an array into an array of dictionaries where each dictionary contains one of the strings and a boolean. Hopefully this makes sense, but I'll try and make a diagram:

At the moment I have:

```
<array>
-<string1>
-<string2>
...
</array>
```

But I want:

```
<array>
-<dictionary1>
--<string1>
--<bool>
-</dictionary1>
-<dictionary2>
--<string2>
--<bool>
-</dictionary2>
...
</array>
```

I've tried creating a loop to cycle through the array of strings, but it doesn't seem to work.

The ultimate goal is to save this new array of dictionaries to the NSUserDefaults (which I'm also fairly unfamiliar with). This is what I have so far, and any help would be much appreciated!

```
// Get the current array from the user defaults.
NSArray *tempArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myArrayKey"];
self.myArray = [tempArray mutableCopy];

// Loop to cycle through the array of strings
for(int i = 0; i < [aList count]; i++)
{
    // Boolean to go in the dictionary with the string.
    checked = NO;

    // Create a dictionary, and set it with two objects and two keys. 
   //First object is the string in the array we are cycling through, the second object is the boolean.
    NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[aList objectAtIndex:i], @"Title", checked, @"checked", nil];

    // Add this dictionary to the new array of dictionaries.
    [self.myArray addObject:tempDict];

    // This NSLog gives me 0 - but gives me  0 seven times (the number of items in the array I am cycling through) so it is definitely cycling through the array.
    NSLog(@"My Array Count: %i", [myArray count]);

    // Release the tempDict.
    [tempDict release];

}

// Write this new array of dictionaries back to NSUseDefaults.
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:myArray forKey:@"myArrayKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: How is the property myArray declared?  Do you have a @synthesize for it?  Are myArray and self.myArray the same?

Comment: Also, does tempArray even exist?  If it's nil, mutableCopy will produce a nil, addObject will accomplish nothing, and [myArray count] will be zero.

Comment: Yeh the problem was because tempArray didn't actually exist, so was nil. When I gave it some values then ran the loop it worked fine. Thanks for your help, think I know what to do to get it working properly now.

Comment: Post it as an answer and I'll tick it if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel pointed out (and I shortly realised through some tests), the fact that the array from NSUserDefaults was nil stopped it from working.

Answer (score -1):

How about inserting a line

```
[tempDict retain];
```

next

> [self.myArray addObject:tempDict];

Comment: I'm not sure if this is perfect answer, but it might solve the problem.

Comment: tempDict is retained by the alloc.  addObject also retains it.  So there should be no need for an additional retain, just the release shown.